# Find query using MongoDb in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB. This is a simple find query. I am not able to see the output.
Is there something I missed. Please guide me.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

connect = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://****:****@cluster0.tioz1.mongodb.net/test")  
db = connect["Company_Management"] 
mycol = db["project"] 
myquery =  {"Pname" : "ProductX"}
mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)
print("Data in the collection: ")
for x in mydoc:
    print(x)
print("end")
```

The obj from MongoDB

```
{
    "1": {
        "Pname": "ProductX",
        "Pnumber": "1",
        "Dname": "Admin",
        "Employee": [{
            "Fname": "John",
            "Lname": "Lewallen",
            "Hours": "2.5"
        }, {
            "Fname": "Lisa",
            "Lname": "Carpenter",
            "Hours": "5.0"
        }, {
            "Fname": "Roy",
            "Lname": "Smith",
            "Hours": "7.0"
        }]
    },
....
}
```

Comment: In MongoDB shell, connect to your database, type `use Company_Management` then `db.project.findOne()` and add the results to your question.

Comment: Your code (syntax) looks alright. Are you able to connect using that _connection string_ from some other tool, like `mongo` shell _or_ Compass?

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I can connect it using Compass